# Sending Push notification in Winjs

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

i am developping a windows store app with html/js , so  my application is a small game and i would like that player 1 can send invitation to player 2 connected with the same app  .so  the push notif appears in the device of player2 and  can choose accept or decline .

I want to know if it's possible with winjs (like C# ) or not?
I am really affraid if there is no a way to achieve that goal.
Any help will be well appreciated 
Please any suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, the push notification mechanism is really just HTTP calls, so not sure where you're concern lies.  There's going to be a bit of infrastructure to support this, but that's required regardless of C# or JavaScript; I can see it transpiring something like:

1. You store a repository of players "in the cloud"
2. Each client downloads (via the app) the list of possible other players to invite.
3. Player 1 indicates he wants to initiate a game with player 2, and that results in a web service call to your cloud service
4. Your web service looks up the channel id(s) for player 2, and pushes the message to devices owned by player 2 via WNS

If you were to use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) you could accomplish this without a lot of work.